# Is it worth making the Answerer name in comments look unique?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find it very useful that in a question, the OP's name in comments has a unique background. After all, they have a unique insight to the question; I view their comments differently.

In the same way, when looking at comments to an answer, I view the answerer's comments differently. Having written the answer, they obviously have a unique insight as well. However, when reading through comments on an answer, I often find myself scrolling back up to the answer to remind myself who actually wrote it, and, well... it's a bit annoying. But only a little bit.

Is it worth displaying an answerer's name differently in the comments on their answer?

(I'm not very good at design, so I don't know if the route to take (if this is deemed worth it) is to change the background color, the text color, or some other change).

Comment: This seems like a decent idea - but it may just be too much work in general. Realistically, comments on good questions/answers shouldn't be to a length where you cannot see the OP or answerer's name any longer. If it is, it may need to be cleaned up. I also wonder if this would give people the wrong idea and create a more "chatty" comment section. Just my two cents.

Comment: why the downvotes? This is a completely legitimate question.  Don't just vote down because your answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Not being able to discern who made what comment in an answer is a smell in and of itself; it means that there are too many comments to begin with.

Comments are meant to be temporal and short-lived.  Emphasizing the OP's comments was a good move since responses to clarifying questions are valuable.  Emphasizing an answerer's comments indicates that there's some information that should be captured in the answer that presently *isn't*.

Comment: Hm... You've got me convinced that answerer comments shouldn't be emphasized, but now I'm wondering why we emphasize OP's comments then (although I'm obviously not going to advocate against it). After all, their comments should be temporal as well; In theory, if they answer a clarifying question in the comments, that's meant to be edited into the question (since apparently that information was required). Is this one of those cases where "in theory" and "in practice" are just too far apart?

Comment: @LordFarquaad: I'd argue that various groups want to make comments into something it really isn't.  People forget to edit questions with important context found in comments, or assume a question is answered in comments.  Theory and practice could be seen as divergent in this light.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I guess there is an argument to be made that it would be important that the OP of a question is to highlighted when  he comments on answers to his question. It is  feasible to not see the question anymore when you are looking at an answer (just a guess, though...)